# How to post trigger firebase cloud functions with express.js

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

What i am trying to do is send data(inputs) from client to firebase cloud function with post trigger using express.js  and use that data to create a new user.
this is the cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.registeration = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

 res.status(400).send({
      message: 'error',
      message2:req,
      message3:req.body
  });
  res.send({
      message: 'success'
  });
});
```

So how do i write client part with express.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
const express = require('express');

// Create the server
const app = express(); 

app.use((err, req, res, _next) => {
  console.log('Error handler', err);
  if(err){
    res.status(400).send({
      message:'error',
      message2:req,
      message3:req.body
    });
  } else {
    res.send({
      message: 'success'
    });
  }
});

exports.registeration = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```